# Access to private Array

Tags: php

As a oop-newbee i get on my limit with this. I took an existing example with 3 items.
I try to append my DB-Content to a existing array but it does not work.
I tryed calling my function from any place within the App but I fail. 
Either I did not find the way filling the Array from the begin as `private static $entries =`  does not allow the call to a function.

How can I fill the array with my data from the DB? And how can I call the function pushEntries correctly?

```
class Model{

    private static $entries = array(
        array("id"=>0, "title"=>"Eintrag 1", "content"=>"Ich bin der erste Eintrag."),
        array("id"=>1, "title"=>"Eintrag 2", "content"=>"Ich bin der ewige Zweite!"),
        array("id"=>2, "title"=>"Eintrag 3", "content"=>"Na dann bin ich die Nummer drei.")
    );

    public static function pushEntries($layerid = 96) {
        require_once('/../pdo_dbconnect.php');
        $sqlAll = 'select beitrag.* from beitrag,menu where beitrag.seitenid = :layerid order by beitrag.sort'; 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sqlAll);  
        $stmt->bindParam(':layerid', $layerid);
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $newdata = array ('id'=>$data['beitragid'],'title'=>$data['titel'],'content'=>$data['beitrag']);        
            $entries[] = $newdata;      
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static properties are accessed via `self::`, so your code should be:

```
self::$entries[] = $newdata;
```

Also you can skip creating `$newdata` array:

```
while ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
    self::$entries[] = array(
        'id'=>$data['beitragid'],
        'title'=>$data['titel'],
        'content'=>$data['beitrag']
    );        
}
```

Comment: Thanks   self::   did the Job.

Answer (score 1):

To access the static properties and methods, you can use the Scope Resolution Operator (::).

From outside of the class you can call the `public static function pushEntries` like this:

```
Model::pushEntries();
```

From inside of the class, you can call the `public static function pushEntries` like this:

```
self::pushEntries();
```

To add data to the `private static $entries` array, you can use `self::$entries[] = $newdata;` in your while loop.

More information about the static keyword can be found on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php